# Autoencoder with Transfer Learning?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, computer-vision, autoencoder, resnet

Is there a way I can train an autoencoder model using a pre-trained model like `ResNet`?

I'm trying to train an autoencoder model with input as an image and output as a masked version of that image.

Is it possible to use weights from a pretrained model here?

Comment: could you include in your question the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! you can definitely do transfer learning using a pre-trained network, i.e. ResNet50 as the encoder in an autoencoder. For reference, check out the following link. https://github.com/hsinyilin19/ResNetVAE

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, there is no proven method to do this. I'd train the autoencoder from scratch.

In theory, if you find a pre-trained CNN which does not use max pooling, you can use those weights and architecture for the encoder stage in your autoencoder. You can also extract features from a pre-trained model and concatenate/merge them to your autoencoder. But the value add is not clear, and the architecture might become overly complex.